# i need to get data from mysql DB and put it to a json array and use the json array for textbox auto complete

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

i need to get data from mysql DB and put it to a json array and use the json array for textbox auto complete. i can do this with separate php for load the data from db and use it in the ajax.. but i am trying to do this with one php file.. is this possible.. how to do this.

```
<script>
$(document).on('keyup','.jornal', function(){
    var thisRow = $(this).data('value');        

    if(event.which != 13){
        //itemSearchDisables(thisRow);
    }
    autoTypeNo2=1 ;
    autoTypeNo1=0 ;

    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'AJAX_Requst/bill_itemDetail.php',
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                  ID: request.term 
                },
                 success: function( data ) {
                     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        var code = item.split("|");
                        if(code[0] == 'Login Please'){
                            //window.location = '../login.php';                                         
                        }
                        return {
                            label: code[autoTypeNo2] + ' | '+ code[3],
                            value: code[autoTypeNo1],
                            data : item
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,            
        minLength: 0,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
            id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
            id = id_arr.split("_");
            //itemSearchEnables(thisRow);
            $('#itemNo_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
            $('#itemName_'+id[1]).text(names[1]);           

        }               
    });

});

</script>
```

This is what i am done up to now to load data..and it is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, create the json array in the same php file and pass that array to the javascript function.. It would be some thing like below

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [<?php $jsonArray ?>];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
```

in that case try using this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Custom data and display</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #project-label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  #project-icon {
    float: left;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
  }
  #project-description {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var projects = [
      {
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
      },
      {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
      },
      {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
      }
    ];

    $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: projects,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
        $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
        $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );

        return false;
      }
    })
    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="project-label">Select a project (type "j" for a start):</div>
<img id="project-icon" src="images/transparent_1x1.png" class="ui-state-default" alt="">
<input id="project">
<input type="hidden" id="project-id">
<p id="project-description"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what about the **filter**  . if i just call the availableTags array as source,     availableTags[0] = 'asd | 156 | STF01' , availableTags[1] = 'nsd | 056 | STF02' , availableTags[2] = 'sad | 106 | STF03' , each array contain other detail that is not for filter, the autocomplete only filter the first part of the array , is this clear !!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible from my point of view. This way you don't have to post ajax form in autocomplete function too.

First you retrieve the data from MySQL database as usual.

Next, you store those data in the javascript `var`.

Last, you can use the `var` for textbox autocomplete.